# Selectively zip files up to 50M

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have to select all the files that starts with `data*` and choose the latest files by date such that the compressed zip file of the selected files should not exceed 50MB. How do I achieve this in bash scripting ?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to know what the zipped size of a set of files is without actually checking.  Are you looking for a program to do this iteratively or something to predict what the zipped size will be ahead of time?

Comment: @user1717828 I am ok with iteratilvely adding files to zip folder and checking the size, but I have to make sure the latest date(time) files are added first and then the next newest and so on

Comment: Do you mind using another scripting language, or does it have to be in bash?

Comment: What should happen if you have, say, 10 files for the same date but you can only fit some of them into your 50M limit?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want something like

```
stat -c "%Y %n" data* | sort -rn | cut -d" " -f2- | 
while IFS= read -r file; do 
    if ! [[ -f my.zip ]]; then
        zip my.zip "$file"
    elif (( $(stat -c %s my.zip) < 50000000 )); then
        zip my.zip "$file"
    else 
        echo "zip file full"
        break
    fi
done
```

The first line sorts the files in the current directory by modifed time, newest to oldest.